# Normalmapping only "working" in negative axis

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, glsl, lwjgl

So basically I'm implementing normal mapping in my 3d program and I'm having an issue where the normal mapping only seems to show on the negative axis, and when I get close to it it is offset and is in the wrong position.

I've tried to do a bunch of stuff including using different methods, multiplying the light direction and camera position instead of the normal map, using a transposed and inversed TBN matrix, checking the texture loading process and turning off all processes that could interfere and a ton more.

Here is my main method in my vertex shader:

```
gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * EyeMatrix * ModelMatrix * vec4(Position, 1.0);
texCoords = TexCoords;
position = (ModelMatrix * vec4(Position, 1.0)).xyz;

vec3 n = normalize((ModelMatrix * vec4(Normal, 0.0))).xyz;
vec3 t = normalize((ModelMatrix * vec4(Tangent, 0.0))).xyz;

t = normalize(t - dot(t, n) * n);

vec3 b = cross(t, n);

tbnMatrix = mat3(t, b, n);
```

Here is how i calculate my lighting:

```
vec3 calculatePointLight(PointLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir, float energyConservation)
{
vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - fragPos);

float diff = max(dot(normal, normalize(lightDir + viewDir)), 0.0);

float spec = energyConservation * pow(max(dot(normal, normalize(lightDir + viewDir)), material.specularIntensity), material.specularDampening);

float distance    = length(light.position - fragPos);
float attenuation = 1.0 / (light.attenuation.constant + light.attenuation.linear * distance + 
             light.attenuation.quadratic * pow(distance, 2.2));    

vec3 ambient  = light.baseLight.ambient * vec3(texture(material.texture_diffuse, texCoords));
vec3 diffuse  = (light.baseLight.diffuse * light.baseLight.intensity) * diff * vec3(texture(material.texture_diffuse, texCoords));
vec3 specular = (light.baseLight.specular * light.baseLight.intensity) * spec * vec3(texture(material.texture_gloss, texCoords));

ambient  *= attenuation;
diffuse  *= attenuation;
specular *= attenuation;

return (ambient + diffuse + specular);
}
```

and here's the code for my normal map:

```
vec3 normal = normalize(tbnMatrix * (255.0/128.0 * texture(material.texture_normal, texCoords).xyz - 1));
```

Here is what the tangents look like:

[image]

Here is what the tangents look like with the TBN matrix applied:

[image]

Here is the T component loaded in (without any editions): [image]
Here is the B component (the one in the vertex shader): [image]
Here is the N component loaded in (without any editions): [image]

And here is what I get when I render the scene with normal mapping: 
[image]
[image]

Here is what it looks like without normal mapping (with mipmapping and anisotropic-filtering enabled):

[image]

(Keep in mind I have specular maps as well)

Comment: It is totally unclear what the images are even supposed to be showing. For example: "Here is what the tangents look like" Which one? The object space one, the one transformed to world space? The one after the re-orthogonalization? My advice would be to first systematically check all your inputs and the model data itself. Also, your diffuse calculation is totally off, you're using `dot(N,H)` instead of `dot(N,L)`.

Comment: I am using a different method it's not incorrect and it doesn't change the results if I use the normal method I was using Blinn-Phong, and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the issue after weeks, and it was a very simple mistake. During the texture loading processing i was using `GL_SRGB` instead of the normal `GL_RGB`, and the SRGB is a gamma corrected version of the texture instead of the actual pure image. So i had to make an option to disable and enable the SRGB loading in the constructor for normal, gloss and displacement maps basically anything that wasn't shown on the screen.